# 'if' statements on C++ template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-warnings

The following code gives me a warning when using the Intel compiler icpc13.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
class base
{
    public:
        double x[N];
};

template<int N>
class derived : public base<2*N>
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            if (N==1)
            {
              std::cout << this->x[1] << std::endl;
            }
            else if (N==2)
            {
              std::cout << this->x[3] << std::endl;
            }
        }

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    derived<1> temp1;
    derived<2> temp2;

    temp1.print();
    temp2.print();
}
```

> Result: % icpc-13.1.163  main.cpp main.cpp(29): warning #175:
>
> subscript out of range std::cout<x[3]<
>
> during instantiation of "void derived::print() [with N=1]" at line
>   41

This is obviously not a danger since the if statement protects this line of code if the template argument is 1.

I know that I "should" do template specialization for such things, but there is some shared code in the real functions that make the if statements on template arguments really handy.

Question is…is this a "bad" thing to do, or is this incorrect compiler behavior? I don't get warnings with gcc, or xlc.

I chose the pragma solution. This ends up looking like this:

```
void print()
{
    #ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
        #pragma warning push
        #pragma warning disable  175
    #endif

    if (N==1)
    {
        std::cout<<this->x[1]<<std::endl;
    }
    else if (N==2)
    {
      std::cout << this->x[3] << std::endl;
    }

    #ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
        #pragma warning pop
    #endif

    }

};
```

From what I can tell, the push saves the warning flags before the disable, and the pop restores them.

Comment: I'm curious if the same warning surfaces if you instead just use: `std::cout<<this->x[2*N-1]<<std::endl;` as our entire function body (and clang give no warning either, so you can add that to your list).

Comment: Using if is fine, you need to check if array index is out of boundary or not. Obviously, if N=2, X[3] is out of boundary and behavior is undefined.

Comment: @billz if `N=2` in the derived class, it is `4` in the base class, where the array is declared. Its not out-of-bounds. That was the purpose of `public base<2*N>`

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right. :)

Comment: It's not a particularly bad thing to do, but I think it's a reasonable warning for the compiler to give. I'd suppress the warning and leave a comment explaining why it's safe.

Comment: @WhozCraig there is no warning if x[2*N-1] is accessed in the function body either. That case should be perfectly legal. I wonder if the compiler should even be checkout code in the if block for anything?

Comment: @AlanStokes wouldn't suppressing the warning allow me to bust array bounds without warning? Is there a way to suppress for a specific block of code? Hmmmmm.

Comment: @doc Sorry, I meant suppress that instance of the warning, not the warning in general. There is usually (or at least sometimes) some way to do this.

Comment: @doc07b5 What Alan refers to is generally `#pragma` directive. Check out [GCC diagnostics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) for more info. You can probably configure the specific warning you want to ditch by surrounding the temporary block with an appropriate diagnostic. But note, your code will be gcc-dependant, as clang and msvc will complain they don't know what that pragma is. Dunno if that is a big deal for you or not.

Comment: @WhozCraig I saw those, and they look what I need…although I wonder if the intel and IBM compilers will recognize the #pragma. I'll give it a shot and post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers do check code branches even they're inactive due to compile-time constants.

ICPC seems to be the only that checks the array bounds, but you could possibly run into other annoying warnings, like from Visual C++, which warns about constant conditional expressions when checking N (C4127 with warning level 4).

I definitely would take care of the warning, your mileage may vary:

- disable warning with compiler option `-wd175`
- disable warning at this specific point with vendor-dependent `#pragma warning(disable: 175)`
- specialize the `derived<>::print()` method and factor out common code:

```c
template<>
void derived<1>::print()
{
    std::cout << x[1] << std::endl;
    call_common();
}
template<>
void derived<2>::print()
{
    std::cout << x[3] << std::endl;
    call_common();
}
```

- factor out the switch on N into its own specialized method `derived<>::print_x()`:

```c
template<>
void derived<1>::print_x()
{
    std::cout << x[1] << std::endl;
}
template<>
void derived<2>::print_x()
{
    std::cout << x[3] << std::endl;
}
template<int N>
void derived<N>::print()
{
    print_x();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I agree with your suggested "fixes". I had wondered if the compiler SHOULD be checking inactive blocks of code due to if statements. I guess I can see why it would, although in this case the fix significantly complicates the code. Thanks

Comment: I went with the pragma. I think that the syntax you gave may be deprecated. I put the solution up.

Comment: You may be right about this, but both syntax versions work with icc 13.0.1 as available during the time of writing on http://gcc.godbolt.org/